# Splitting of characters in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

A1 cell having 130 characters and A2 cell  having 129 characters and A3 cell  having 23 characters and vice versa till A100 cell. Now I need first 100 characters from A1 cell should placed in B1 and next 100 characters (30 from A1 cell and next 70 characters from A2 cell ) should be place in B2 cell and it should continues for till A100 cell.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a coding service - you should show what you have attempted but to get you started and note I have not tested this - improving is up to you :

In cell B1 you should put:

```
=left(A1,100)
```

and in cell B2:

```
=mid(A1,101,30)&left(A2,70)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need a helper column to do this, or may be append to a single formula itself,

If data is present in `column A`, enter the below formula in cell`B1` (Helper cell),

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,A2,A3,A4,A5)
```

Since you have data from `A1` to `A100`, all the cells has to be included in the formula in `B1`. I have just made with 5 values to show an example.

Enter the below formula in cell `C1` and drag down till there is no value left over,

```
=MID($B$1,(ROW()-1)*5+1,5)
```

Since i'm just splitting with 5 character-length strings, i have used `5` in the formula. You have to change both the `5`s to `100` as you need length of 100 characters.

[image]